# Choice of Wire Gauge for 5v 26A LED Power Line

Tags: power-supply, wire, led-strip

I am planning on having a large number of programmable LED strips powered by a 5v 150W supply I got from Digikey.  The LEDs (APA102) will be controlled using an Arduino, which will also be powered by the same supply. The 5v supply will be wired to the LED strips individually.  The total number of strips will be 32 (30-60cm lengths) hanging from the ceiling.  The longest run of the 5v power line will be 10 meters.  The highest current, near the supply, will be 25A.

Do you know what gauge wire I should use for the 5v supply line?

I was thinking of sacrificing a good power cable and having the strips soldered to the cable at various points. Do you think this should work well and safely?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Figure out what temperature rise above ambient would be safe, and put all that into one of the dozens of wire gauge calculators across the Internet.

Comment: Do you HAVE to have all the strips on the same power line? I think it theory it is possible, but it might be wiser to divide and conquer.

Comment: I have found lots of information and tables regarding AC, as well as higher voltage DC. But I have not found anything for 5 V DC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are LEDs that have an integrated processor. So unlike a typical LED, controlling the voltage, instead of the current, to each LED is the primary design goal. As such, the issue of wire gauge becomes a question of voltage drop in the wire due to the current passing through the wire.

The LED spec sheet does not specify a minimum voltage but instead lists a typical voltage of 5.0 and a maximum of 5.5. For the purpose of this analysis, we will assume a minimum voltage of 4.75 volts. The maximum current per chip is 26.5 mA. Assuming 60 LED chips per meter, a 60 cm strip would draw 36 * 26.5 mA or ~ 1 amp.

To provide no less than 4.75 volts per strip, the wiring must have no more than 0.25 volts / 1 amp or 0.25 ohms. The longest wire length is 10 meters but there will be twice that in total wire length to account for the positive and negative wires. This gives us a resistance budget of 0.25 ohms / 20 meters or 0.0125 ohms per meter. Consulting a copper wire chart, 15 ga wire or larger would be suitable.

By following the above math, you can calculate the minimum wire gauge for any number of LEDs per wire run.

Given the large total current of the supply, it would be wise to fuse the various wire runs in no more than 5 amps per segment. The fuses should be located at the supply connector.

Comment: That was great, thanks.  I was assuming the APA102 can draw a max of 20mA per LED (R G and B) totalling 60mA per chip.  At 30/m, that is 1.8A per strip.  So, 0.25v/1.8A=0.139 ohms, and so over 20m that would be  0.006 ohms/m.  The chart I found indicates I would need 13 gauge minimum.  I like limiting the fuses to 5A each, so that would be a fuse for 3 strips.  What about the wire limitations due to current at 5v, especially at the power supply output that feeds all the fuses?

Comment: For the distribution bus, use a short section of 10 ga or larger wire. 1 meter of 10 ga wire is 0.00328 ohms. This times 25 amps is an additional voltage drop of 0.082 volts.

Comment: Great.  And how can I find out about the high current (25A at source) at 5v?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but isn't there a safety concern with too much current moving in a wire, and a certain thickness is needed?  I was wondering what that gauge would be for 26A 5v.

Comment: 1 meter of 10 ga wire at 25 amps will dissipate 2 watts of heat (25 amps * 25 amps * 0.00328 ohms). With 6 ga wire this would drop to 0.8 watts. Build the distribution bus so it has adequate air circulation and is not near any flammable materials. And of course, keep it as short as possible.

Comment: So, if the longest run is 10m, using 13 gauge wire at 5A, would the power dissipation be 0.00656 ohms/m x 10m  x 5A x 5A = 1.64W?

Comment: Yes, if 10 meters is the total (plus and minus leads) length.

Comment: Ok, so twice that, 3.28w.  But isn't that dissipated over the entire wire in a non linear fashion? I'm not sure where to go from here, though, in terms of figuring out safety.  Please excuse my ignorance.  I am learning a fair bit from you, thanks.

Comment: It is spread along the wire in a largely linear fashion so 0.328 watts per linear meter split between two wires. Consider that in the USA, 14 ga wire is allowed to carry 15 amps RMS. It is good to be thinking about heat rise and dissipation but your numbers are low enough you should do some prototyping and checking actual temperature rise. Check the wire insulation specs for your measured temperature rise.

Comment: Great!  You are certainly helping out here. How can the temperature rise be measured?  Again, noob question.

Comment: Basic test, feel the wire for warmth. Better test, use an IR thermometer. Professional test, use an IR camera. You will likely find that you cannot even feel any additional warmth. Then you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you once again for your help.  I have learned a lot, and it was very well explained.

Comment: My pleasure. Have fun!